# A request by user by browser and why more requests made

Tags: request

when i open a site and submit a form, the browser show the response content.

but after i sniff by fiddler, i found more get/post requests sent by browser or js and they are not sent by ajax because no XMLHttpRequest in header. the response content-type are text/html.

so browser should show the new response content,right? but NOT. it still show the first.

1, how browser send more request? i guess they are made by javascript.

2, why browser did not show new content?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it does sound like a client-side scripting language, most likely JavaScript;
2. It can be an AJAX load. AJAX does not have to be XMLHttpRequest, although most ajax implementations use XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: open https://signup.wordpress.com/signup  and fill and submit this form and you will find some more requests sent and response with text/html. but browser did not show new content. so possibly, they are all ajax right?

Comment: Yes. AJAX (or Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) is just a name people give to the action of "loading new stuff without refreshing the page", and it does not reflect any specific implementation details. As of the content type, you can set the content-type to anything in jQuery.ajax (and very likely in all other ways of doing ajax, but I'm not familiar with those).